# Help understanding the mixer of a superhetrodyne receiver

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, rf, circuit-design

I studied all the datasheets and read a book on the basics of RF front end design. I know the receive circuit is a superhetrodyne.

I see in the datasheet the output of the mixer at pin 4 is the |f1-f2| and pin 5 is f1+f2. I understand the far left op-amp is a infinite gain 2nd order active bandpass filter. I am trying to understand what happens to the mixer outputs as they travel though the middle and left op-amp, since both mixer outputs are fed through.

Can you help me understand this circuit? The input is an 8Mhz OOK signal. The output is a 128kHz image of the input into a purpose built AFE.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

U5A is a differential amplifier with a gain of 5. U5B is not "infinite gain". It is a 2-pole bandpass filter with a peak gain of about 15 dB at 128 kHz.

So the outputs of the mixer are filtered to remove any DC component by the first op amp, and the result is bandpass filtered at the expected modulation frequency. In the absence of a signal (zero amplitude) the output will be whatever noise has been detected at about 128 kHz. At ON amplitude, the output will reflect whatever the signal strength was. And since the filter is low Q (about 1) the rise and fall times of the output will be short.

Answer (score 1):

Pin 4 and pin 5 are differential outputs.  f1+f2 and f1-f2 (as well as f1, f2, 2f1+f2, 2f1-f2, 2f2+f1, 2f2-f1, etc.) come out of both of these ports.  U5A then performs a differential to single ended conversion, with R16/R17 generating a 'zero' reference, filtered by C22.  Looks like U5B is an active filter of some sort.

Comment: SA612 is a double-balanced mixer. So gain for f1, f2 is much smaller at the two mixer outputs, relative to the +18 dB gain for (f1+f2) and the desired (f1-f2). In any case, U5A op-amp has little gain at f1, f2, (f1+f2) frequencies.

Comment: True, but those products will still be generated at some level. My point is that all of the possible mixer products come out of the same output port, the mixer doesn't send the sum out of one port and the difference out of a different port.

Answer (score 0):

Your chosen OpAmp has 10MHz UnityGainBandwidth, and will only poorly filter out the 8MHz LO leakage, the 8.125 RF, and the 16.125 Sum. [ With high SNR OOK, you may be able to be casual about presence of spurious products on your signal recovery.] Additionally, parasitic capacitance across the resistors (0.5pF) creates a HighPass response for the very-sharp-edged mixer chopping waveforms; Stage#1 will pass thru these fast edges, due to parasitics. Stage#2 has a 39pF that lets fast edges bypass the BandPass action.

---

Using SignalChainExplorer, with 10MHz UGBW OpAmp and 0.5pF across Rin&Rfb and 3pF Cindiff per datasheet, we see high-frequency trash leaving that first opamp, because of 0.5pF Cparasitic across Rin(10Kohm) and Rfb(39Kohm). In left hand plot, using pure-resistor feedback (stage1 only), notice 8MHz is only down 12dB. In middle plot, using 0.5pF in parallel with 10K and 39K, we have a few dB more drop at 8MHz BUT a reversal of attenuation above 100MHz, where the mixer's chopping action produces lots of high frequency trash the OpAmp/parasitics cannot reject. In right hand plot, where we also enable the 3pF Cinput_differential per the datasheet, the BODE seems flatter, because that 3pF adds phaseshift to the response and produces a bit of peaking.
[image]

And using SignalWaveExplorer, to examine the "bandpass filter", I don't have the same exact circuit as you, but this below shows how a 10MHz opamp will fail to suppress 8MHz mixer RF or LO energy:
[image]
You can get either of these tools for free: robustcircuitdesign.com

I had the pleasure of exploring Mixer products, using NE602, the brother of NE612. Project was down-conversion of TV channels 2/3/4 to 46MHz IF, into a SAW, into a phase-locked synchronous-demodulation of the NTSC TV composite video. Result was 60+dB SNR and exquisite color reproduction. How?

We used a L+C filter between the differential IF outputs of the NE612/602. Why?

My first IF was a cascode, for low MillerEffect, so the desired IF image was boosted before a Siemens saw filter.

To avoid overloading the cascode amplifier, with unneeded mixer products, given any overloading would generation Intermodulation products, that post-mixer L+C was our friend.

You signal is OOK, likely rather robust against tainting with faint IM.

If you explore dense constellations, where slight energy trash upsets the points of the constellation, you may need to filter right at Pins 4&5. The internal resistors (collectors of the Mixer's LO chopping bipolars) are 1Kohm.
Thus you know the Rsource involved in achieving any particular L+C Q.